# How to be more specific on generic constraints?

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns

I am having the following type where `T` should only be of `int`, `double`, `string` and `datetime`. However using a constraint on `class` would be too broad.

```
public class Field<T> where T : class 
{
    public int Tag { get; set; }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Possible solutions that come to my mind:

1. Add a constructor that does a check (`if ((typeof(T) != typeof(string)) ...`)
2. Change the class to be abstract and move `Value` to the concrete implementing class. This however would result in having several additional types, like `StringField : Field`, `DateTimeField : Field`, etc.

Also I would like to be more specific about the `Tag` property and replace it with an enum, which ensures that only values of predefined range can be used. This approach however would result in a (tiny) overhead, as I need to instance representation of `Field` as a string.

What would be the best model to choose? Anything I am missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, even if you **could** create a constraint that fits all your cases, how you **use** it? There is absoluetely nothing common between `int`, `double` and `string` (except `Equals` and `GetHashCode`), making generics quite useless.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295), what are you trying to achieve with such constraint?

Comment: @HimBromBeere, you are correct. I missed that `string` was in the list of types there in the question. I therefore vote to reopen because i incorrectly flagged a wrong duplicate...

Comment: Use Option 2 - it is likely your best bet. _Although this is very opinion based._

Comment: If something should "only be of int, double, string and datetime", then: it isn't generics; the entire point of generics is to **not** constrain the T (beyond a few categories, not including this one); but: yes, option 1 would work - I'd probably make it a static constructor, so it doesn't run per-instance

Comment: Some quick background: The purpose of this class is to be a building block of a FIX message, which basically is a concatenated string of `Fields` in the form `8=FIX.4.3|35=W|...`. According to the FIX spec a fields value can only be of the before mentioned types. @mjwills if I choose option 2, then I will end up having a class for each field type, where the only shared property will be `int Tag`. Would this be a case for a factory pattern?

Comment: Sorry, I am a kinda confuse on this. I am trying to find out, what my best options are and how I "correctly" leverage C# languages specifics and OO paradigms.

Comment: Have you looked at using a C# FIX library (e.g. http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/receiving-messages.html)?

Comment: @mjwills, yes I did. How or why is this relevant to my question?

Comment: My apologies. Have a great day / night.